# Make Scaffold create a Drawer but not create the drawer related icon button in the app-bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My app uses a `Drawer` to present an item properties inspector by means of `endDrawer:`.

The `Drawer` appears, then an item gets clicked. It disappears, when the properties inspector performs its save operation.

Thus, there is no need to make the `Drawer` come in using a click on the drawer icon button in the app-bar.

If endDrawer is set, navigation arrow does not appear, but space gets consumed:

[image]

If endDrawer isn't set, back arrow gets its space:

[image]

**How to tell `Scaffold` prepare a `Drawer` passed via `drawer:` or `endDrawer:`, but not insert the related icon button in the app-bar?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `SizedBox.shrink()` in`leading` widget in `Appbar` .
and if you want to show back button instead of drawer button , you can simply use `BackButton` like this :

```dart
AppBar(
  leading: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) return BackButton();
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thx! Unfortunately, this hides the back arrow from Navigator too. The Drawer Icon did replace the Navigator back arrow too.

Comment: please check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you, Hosam! Works as expected. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `automaticallyImplyLeading: false` on AppBar

```dart
drawer: Drawer(),
appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    ),
```

Comment: Thx! Doesn't change anything and thus like to other proposal: The leading consumes space, keeps being empty and Navigator back arrow doesn't get inserted.

Comment: How about using `leadingWidth: 0`, Can in you include an image pointing the issue

Comment: Same behavior as before.

Comment: Are you using `endDrawer` or `drawer`? It would be easy if you can provide sample snippet

Comment: Ah, please excuse: endDrawer. Refined my question.

Comment: Similar behavior, if I switch from endDrawer: to drawer:

Comment: Can you include [/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thx! Going to post something tomorrow++.